# Sum exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$-\sqrt{\lambda}t-\lambda(1-e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}})=-\sqrt{\lambda}t+\lambda(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}+...)=\frac{t^2}{2}\text{ as lambda aprroaches infinity}$$

How did we get to $\frac{t^2}{2}$

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not that good at this. I know how to expand e. The 1 cancels out leaving those terms in the brackets. I don't know what to do if we take the limit as lambda goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it now. Thanks Yves. Multiplying lambda into the brackets and subtracting the term outside we are left with $(\frac{t}{2}+....) $ all the other terms have lambda as the denominator.